# Axios post is giving me an error: Internal server Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am doing a post request with Axios and gives me this error:

> xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/dependentes 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

I have seen people asking about this but none of their solutions work for me!
I don't know if is something wrong in this component or I have something wrong with the server side.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class LogIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeEmail = this.handleChangeEmail.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePass = this.handleChangePass.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeEmail = e => {
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    //console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  handleChangePass = e => {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
    //console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    /*this.props.history.push('/');
        console.log(this.props);*/

    event.preventDefault();

    let data = JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    });
    let url = "http://localhost:3000/dependentes";
    const response = axios.post(url, data, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Log In</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              onChange={this.handleChangeEmail}
              value={this.state.email}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              onChange={this.handleChangePass}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn orange lighten-1 z-depth-0">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LogIn;
```

Comment: that is returned by the server, you need to fix the server not react ui. and it looks like you are sending the request to react ui server, did you change the default port?

Comment: what is your `localhost:3000` by default localhost:3000 is used by front end like react. So.. are you `post`ing to your front end route? or you have any proxy set up or a reverse nginx proxy?

Comment: I created a server with nodejs on port 3000. I jsut changed the port to 4000, react is now on port 3000

Comment: where does react run? did you change the default react port which is also 3000?

Comment: yes i did that. It still gives me the same error

Comment: please share nodejs code.

Comment: if you changed the port to 4000 for nodejs, won;t this be `http://localhost:4000/dependentes`?

Comment: yes i changed all that!

Comment: So, then edit the question add this information there. Also post the node.js backend code. Did you add cors? Otherwise it won't connect.

Comment: I will link the code.Yes i did. 
https://jsfiddle.net/z52bvtf6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your node.js code you are NOT using `body-parser` that's why getting email from `req.body` will throw you an error because `req.body` is undefined.

Also, If you don't return the request like `res.send` or `res.json` it will always time out from front end as the request is not closed.

So, to edit your code

```
//installed express, mysql, cors

const config = require('./database/config');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 4000;
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // <=== this line
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //<=== This line

const SELECT_ALL_ADDICTS_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM viciados';

const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.mysql);

connection.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Homepage. Go to /dependentes para ver os dependentes no sistema');
  res.end();
});

app.get('/dependentes', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(SELECT_ALL_ADDICTS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json({
        data: results
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/dependentes', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.email);
  res.json({ email: req.body.email }); ///<== and this line
});

app.listen(port, err => {
  return err
    ? console.log(`error founded: ${err}`)
    : console.log(`server runnning on port: ${port}`);
});
```